# Create new active solution platform (VS2008)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, x86, platform, configurationmanager

I have a project configured for “Any CPU”.  When I go to solution properties, under Configuration Manager -> Active Solution Platform I can see only:

```
Any CPU
<New…>
<Edit…>
```

I want to change it to x86, so I select  and am presented with another dialog that asks me where I want to copy the settings from.

What does this actually mean?  Which settings does it copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's talking about project settings (build directories, reference, etc), but since you have only one active configuration just choose to copy settings from it ("Any CPU").